# Angular-ui FullCalendar open modal on eventClick feature in ionic framwork

Tags: angularjs, events, modal-dialog, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I am using Ionic framework,I have successfully ported the fullCalender to my project,

I can able to call a funtion on eventClick, even it gives the alert of that event title perfectly.

But my main objective is to open the ionic modal instead of alert() with event title.

The code works till the alert comes, I am new to ionic need some idea how to acheive this.So far I have witten the code below

app.js Code:

```
 $scope.calOptions = {
              editable : true,
              header : {
              left: 'prev',
              center: 'title,today',
              right: 'next'
              },
              eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
               var a=calEvent.description;
               var b=calEvent.title;
               alert('ALERT-1:' +a );

                 $scope.safeApply(function()
                 {
                 alert('ALERT-2:' + calEvent.description);
                 $scope.eventModal(a,b)
                 });
};


  $scope.eventModal=function(a,b){
  alert('ALERT-3:'+b);
  $scope.eventModal.show();
  }
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
        $scope.eventModal = $ionicModal;
    },{
        scope: $scope,
        // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });
```

To be more clear the above code shows that the "`eventClick`:" works till "ALERT-3" ,however,on event click it calls the function "`$scope.eventModal=function(a,b)`" but after that at the next line at   `$scope.eventModal.show();` it says that "`show is not a function`", I want to open modal with variables passed to "`$scope.eventModal=function(a,b)`" function.

Need an idea to acheive open the modal with parameters passed to the "`$scope.eventModal=function(a,b)`".

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some simplier:

```
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
        $scope.a = calEvent.description;
        $scope.b = calEvent.title;
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

And inside modal, you can bind {{::a}} and {{::b}} or whatever you want do with them.